# Config class - follow-up

Tags: c#

Original question: [Basic Config Class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/108967/basic-config-class)

One problem I know about is `Initialize()` not being threadsafe, which I am sorting as we speak, so please disregard that.

```
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Apple.Application.Base.Config
{
    internal class AppleConfig
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// List of configuration items
        /// </summary>
        private Dictionary<string, string> _configItems;

        /// <summary>
        /// Config file info
        /// </summary>
        private readonly FileInfo _configFile;

        /// <summary>
        /// Log4net logger.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly ILog _log;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if class has been initialized.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly bool _initialized;

        /// <summary>
        /// AppleConfig constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileP=path"></param>
        public AppleConfig(string filepath)
        {
            if (_initialized)
                return;

            _configItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            _configFile = new FileInfo(filepath);
            _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AppleConfig));
            _initialized = Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes AppleConfig
        /// </summary>
        private bool Initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(_configFile.FullName).Where(IsConfigurationLine))
                {
                    var splittedLine = line.Split('=');

                    String key = splittedLine[0];
                    String value = splittedLine[1];

                    _configItems[key] = value;
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _log.Error(exception); // assuming overload that takes an exception.
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks for valid config line
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Line">String to check</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool IsConfigurationLine(string line)
        {
            return !line.StartsWith("#") && line.Contains("=");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a config items value by its key.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Key">Config Key</param>
        /// <returns>Config Value</returns>
        public string GetConfigElement(string key)
        {
            if (!IsInitialized)
                return null;

            return _configItems[key];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks if class has been initialized.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsInitialized
        {
            get { return _initialized; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Refreshes config
        /// </summary>
        public void RefreshConfig()
        {
            if (!_initialized)
                return;

            Initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` check in your constructor is unnecessary, since `_initialized` will always be false at that point.

Comment: The `if` in `RefreshConfig` is unnecessary, since you always want to re-initialize the config when necessay, won't you?

Comment: But refreshing config would only be called after the config has actually initialized for the first time, if I remove that wouldn't it just make no sense in having that function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Merging some of the suggestions you've received so far this is what I think it should look like (*I removed the comments for this review*):

```
internal class AppleConfig
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _configItems = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private readonly string _fileName;

    private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(AppleConfig));

    public AppleConfig(string fileName)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;

        // first time we want it to work
        if(!LoadConfig())
        {
            throw new Exception("Initalization failed.");
        }
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        // this might throw an exception if key not found
        get { return _configItems[key]; }
    }

    public bool IsInitialized
    {
        get { return _configItems != null; }
    }

    public bool LoadConfig()
    {
        try
        {
            _configItems =
                File.ReadLines(_fileName)
                    .Where(IsConfigurationLine)
                    .Select(line => line.Split('='))
                    .ToDictionary(line => line[0], line => line[1]);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _log.Error(exception); // assuming overload that takes an exception.
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool IsConfigurationLine(string line)
    {
        return !line.StartsWith("#") && line.Contains("=");
    }
}
```

- You don't need the `_isInitialized` field, you can check the dictionary if it's not null
- You don't need the *big* loop but just a short linq query (by [@Konrad Morawski](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/108993/59161))
- You don't need the `Initialize` method and all the crazy logic ;-) but a simple `LoadConfig` method that you call in the constructor and later if you want to load it again
- You don't need the `FileInfo` class but just a simple string for the path
- There's still a lot that *might* be *improved* but it all depends how you are going to use it and whether you need all the improvements at all: will someone else use it? Do you need/want meaningful exceptions (I think it's always hard to implement them if you want them to make it possible to find an error right away).
- After all I think the `IsInitialized` property is also not necessary, it doesn't have any usage. The object cannot actually be in an un-initialized state beacause it would be useless then so I would say it can be removed without losing anything. The load method either worked and everything is fine or it didn't and the constuructor throws an exception.

Comment: Marked as correct answer and voted up. I have merged my existing class and used some of your tips posted here, the final version can be viewed here https://gist.github.com/JoshHallow/36a86e305452e54ae639

One thing I am not sure about is locking, and actually making this class 100% threadsafe, any tips on that?

Comment: @LiamHardy I think this is thread safe because you will probably load it when you applications starts and then just read from it. There is no chance something can go wrong. You need to worry about threads when you start writing new values to your config. Currently, I think it's unnecessary and the load method can be guarded with a simple lock what might be all you need right now.

Comment: Okay thanks, when you say theres still a lot to improve how do you mean? can you further on that..

Comment: @LiamHardy ;-) you know, all the parameter checking if the file name is not null, whether it exists... if you want to throw more meaningful exceptions then the internal ones. The default indexer can unexpectedly throw an exception if you pass it a non-existing key, you might consider using an enum for example instead of a string key. But you might not need all this, if you and only you will use it somewhere internally. It's hard to say.

Comment: You mean something like below?

if (file.Length < 1)
                    throw new NullReferenceException("Configuration file cannot be null.");

Comment: @LiamHardy yes, it can be anything, a number of config items, mandatory keys, etc. etc.

Comment: I'd only add that the XML-doc should only be on the public members, them being *everywhere* is a little overkill. Implementation details need self-documenting code, not XML comments.